# GCPにVPNで接続したい

Tags: google-cloud

### 前提

VPN という概念は知識として知っていますが、構築は今回が初めてです。

---

### 発生している問題

ローカルの PC から VPN で GCP に接続したいのですが、 GCP のファイアフォールの設定が甘いのか、 ping が飛ばないです。

ローカルのルーターはヤマハの RTX1200 で、問題なく接続を示す UP が表示されており、 GCP についても VPN トンネルは「確立済み」が表示されております。

VPC ネットワークも作成済みで

- IP アドレス範囲：`192.168.200.0/24`
- ゲートウェイ：`192.168.200.1`
- 限定公開の Google アクセス：オフ

と設定しています。

VM (Linux) についても、

- プライマリ内部 IP：`192.168.200.2`
- 外部 IP：（エフェメラル）

なのですが、
ローカルからの ping (`192.168.200.2`とエフェメラル) を受け付けない状態です。

また、ブラウザからの SSH も受け付けません。
デフォルトのネットワークでも VM を起動していますが、そちらは問題なく SSH がつながります。

おそらくFWの設定と思うのですが、この場合どう設定すれば良いか、ご教授をお願いします。

---

### 追記

接続ができるようになり、 PING およびローカルからの ssh が可能となりました (GCP 側の FW の設定 `tcp:22` を IP 範囲 `0.0.0.0/0` で設定)。

ただ、常時接続とはいかず、定期的に切断される状態です。
常時接続する場合の設定について、ご教授をお願いします。

---

### Yamaha ルータの設定内容

```
tunnel select 1
 description tunnel vpngcp
 ipsec tunnel 101
  ipsec sa policy 101 1 esp aes-cbc sha-hmac
  ipsec ike version 1 2
  ipsec ike always-on 1 on
  ipsec ike encryption 1 aes-cbc
  ipsec ike group 1 modp1024
  ipsec ike hash 1 sha
  ipsec ike keepalive log 1 on
  ipsec ike keepalive use 1 on icmp-echo 192.168.200.2
  ipsec ike local address 1 192.168.0.1
  ipsec ike local name 1 <自分のグローバルIP> ipv4-addr
  ipsec ike pfs 1 on
  ipsec ike pre-shared-key 1 text <自分で設定したパスワード>
  ipsec ike remote address 1 <GCPのVPN用IP>
  ipsec ike remote name 1 <GCPのVPN用IP> ipv4-addr
  ipsec auto refresh 1 on
 ip tunnel tcp mss limit auto
 tunnel enable 1
```

Comment: Yamahaルーターの設定内容を 可能な範囲で質問文を編集して追記してみてもらえますか？ NW関連の質問は、質問者さんがお使いの環境が わからないと 第三者からの回答はつきにくいと思います。その他にも ヒントになりそうな点がアレば、どんどん質問を「編集」して情報量を増やしてみてください！

Comment: ルータの設定を追記しました。また、質問内容を一部修正しました。